# How To Update SQL Table Record with Regex

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

I have `User` table in my database with a column `AvatarUrl` with the following value:

```
https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/5811b64ffd2fa7116580dafa02d9bb7b?s=360&d=identicon&r;=PG
```

Now I want to update all `AvatarUrl` by changing `?s=xx` query string that it is avatar size. I do search for find regex, so I find it but I don't know that how can I do this in SQL.

Query string regex: `([\?\&])s=[^\&]+[\&]?`

Comment: You can't. Sql Server does not support regular expressions. (Well, you can probably use a CLR function, but that's not pure t-sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that kind of stuff (change parameters in url) we use this function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.change_url_param (
    @string nvarchar(max),
    @param nvarchar(max),
    @newvalue nvarchar(max)
)
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @params nvarchar(max),
            @first nvarchar(1) = N'?',
            @next nvarchar(1) = N'&',
            @p nvarchar(max) = N'',
            @v nvarchar(max) = N''

    DECLARE @tmp TABLE (
        [param] nvarchar(max),
        [value] nvarchar(max)
    )

    SELECT @params = '&'+SUBSTRING(@string,CHARINDEX(@first,@string)+1,LEN(@string)-CHARINDEX(@first,@string)+1)
    SELECT @string = LEFT(@string,CHARINDEX(@first,@string))

    WHILE ISNULL(CHARINDEX(@next,@params),0) > 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT @p = SUBSTRING(@params,CHARINDEX(@next,@params),CHARINDEX('=',@params))
        SELECT @params = RIGHT(@params,LEN(@params) - LEN(@p))

        SELECT @v = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(@next,@params) = 0  THEN @params ELSE SUBSTRING(@params,1,CHARINDEX(@next,@params)-1) END
        SELECT @params = RIGHT(@params,LEN(@params) - LEN(@v))


        INSERT INTO @tmp VALUES (REPLACE(REPLACE(@p,'&',''),'=',''), @v)
    END

    SELECT @params = N''

    UPDATE @tmp
    SET [value] = @newvalue
    WHERE [param] = @param

    SELECT @params = @params + @next + [param] + '=' + [value]
    FROM @tmp

    RETURN @string + RIGHT(@params,LEN(@params)-1)

END
```

It is old, but works fine.

If you make:

```
-- change parameter `s` to `560`
SELECT [dbo].[change_url_param] (N'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/5811b64ffd2fa7116580dafa02d9bb7b?s=360&d=identicon&r;=PG','s','560')
```

Output will be:

```
https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/5811b64ffd2fa7116580dafa02d9bb7b?s=560&d=identicon&r;=PG
```

To use it with a table:

```
UPDATE dbo.your_table
SET [URL] = [dbo].[change_url_param] ([URL],'s','800')
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use the PATINDEX function to find the positions of your '?s=' and '&d=' and then replace the string in between

Answer (score 1):

You can't use Regex per se, but PATINDEX & STUFF should make it easy enough...

```
DECLARE @AvatarURL VARCHAR(1000) = 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/5811b64ffd2fa7116580dafa02d9bb7b?s=360&d=identicon&r;=PG'

SELECT 
    STUFF(@AvatarURL, ps.pat_start, 1, '&')
FROM
    ( VALUES (PATINDEX('%?s=[0-9][0-9]%', @AvatarURL)) ) ps (pat_start);
```

output...

```
https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/5811b64ffd2fa7116580dafa02d9bb7b&s=360&d=identicon&r;=PG
```

edited to show a how it would look as an update statement...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MyURLs', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #MyURLs;

CREATE TABLE #MyURLs (
    AvatarURL VARCHAR(1000) 
    );
INSERT #MyURLs VALUES 
    ('https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/5811b64ffd2fa7116580dafa02d9bb7b?s=360&d=identicon&r;=PG');

-- take a peek at the original values...
SELECT [Before] = mul.AvatarURL FROM #MyURLs mul;

-- use an update to correct the bad character.
UPDATE mul SET  
    mul.AvatarURL = STUFF(mul.AvatarURL, ps.pat_start, 1, '&')
FROM
    #MyURLs mul
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (PATINDEX('%?s=[0-9][0-9]%', mul.AvatarURL)) ) ps (pat_start);

-- final product...
SELECT [After] = mul.AvatarURL FROM #MyURLs mul;
```

Results...

```
Before
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/5811b64ffd2fa7116580dafa02d9bb7b?s=360&d=identicon&r;=PG

After
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/5811b64ffd2fa7116580dafa02d9bb7b&s=360&d=identicon&r;=PG
```

Comment: @SoheilAlizadeh - Sorry for the slow reply, I've updated my answer to include an update statement.